# Android emulator (unfortunately app has stopped)

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, logcat

I am using eclipse to develop an android app. I am using a web service to connect to SQL Server database. When I run the app on the emulator, an error message appears saying: `"Unfortunately (my app name) has stopped". I don't know what is the reason for that message.`

The application was work correctly without errors. But I don't know what I added to stop it

The LogCat shows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(805): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-80
E/AndroidRuntime(805): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
E/AndroidRuntime(805):  at com.project.sbms.wbsCall.Call(wbsCall.java:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(805):  at com.project.sbms.wbsThread.run(wbsThread.java:14)
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have ksoap2 or the ksoap2 serialization package on your path. Make sure the JAR file is in the `/libs` folder, that way it will be automatically included by android.